XSLT 3.0: Puzzling behaviour of <xsl:value-of> in the context of <xsl:sort> when multiple siblings of the sort-key are present
Expanding on an example of the XSLT 3.0 spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#sorted-iteration I wanted to see error [err-XTTE1020] (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#err-XTTE1020) in action which states:

“If any sort key value (…) is a sequence containing more than one
item, then the effect depends on whether the xsl:sort element is
processed with XSLT 1.0 behavior. With XSLT 1.0 behavior, the
effective sort key value is the first item in the sequence. In other
cases, this is a type error.”

and so I added a second  name to one of the employees, Mr. James Clark who is now Mr. James Maxwell Clark.
This is my XML:
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <given>Petula</given>
      <family>Clark</family>
    </name>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>
      <given>James</given>
      <given>Maxwell</given>
      <family>Clark</family>
    </name>
  </employee>
    <employee>
    <name>
      <given>John</given>
      <family>Berry</family>
    </name>
  </employee>
</employees>

As expected, the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet produced the error ín question at runtime:
<?xml version="3.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="employees">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Employees</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>Employees</h1>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
                        <xsl:sort select="name/family" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:sort select="name/given" order="ascending"/>
                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                </ul>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="name/given"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="name/family"/>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Error: XTTE1020: The result ...
As a way to solve this I simply figured I'll add a predicate to the sort-key specifying the position of the <given>-sibling desired as the sort key. So I changed my stylesheet to (excerpt):
(...)
<xsl:apply-templates select="employee">
    <xsl:sort select="name/family" order="ascending"/>
    <xsl:sort select="name/given[1]" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
(...)

This indeed eliminated the error and the stylesheet ran through, albeit producing the following output (excerpt):
<ul>
    <li>John Berry</li>
    <li>James Maxwell Clark</li>
    <li>Petula Clark</li>
</ul>

So now suddenly the simple <xsl:value-of select="name/given"/> in <xsl:template match="employee"> seems to produce the text-nodes of both <given>-siblings as if it was surrounded by an <xsl:for-each>!
This I cannot explain.
Swapping the stylesheet-version to "1.0" does not help to explain this, since version "1.0", as explained by the error description above, simply took the first <given> as its sort-key and ignored the rest of the siblings. And doing the <xsl:sort select="name/given1"/>-trick in version "1.0" produces the expected output, i.e.
<li>James Clark</li>

Can anybody shed light on this behaviour? Possibly with references to the relevant section(s) of the XSLT 3.0 spcification?
I am using (have to use) Altova XMLSpy 2024.

In XSLT 2 or 3 processors with default processing (i.e. not with backwards compatible XSLT 1.0 processing) xsl:value-of select="some-sequence" (in your sample code and data <xsl:value-of select="name/given"/> can select a sequence of given elements with one or two elements) outputs a text node with a separator delimited sequence of the string values of each item in the sequence. The default separator is a single space, it can be changed with a separator attribute on the xsl:value-of giving a different separator.
https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#value-of:

The xsl:value-of instruction is evaluated to construct a new text
node; the result of the instruction is the newly constructed text
node.
The string value of the new text node may be defined either by using
the select attribute, or by the sequence constructor (see 5.7 Sequence
Constructors) that forms the content of the xsl:value-of element.
These are mutually exclusive: if the select attribute is present then
the sequence constructor must be empty, and if the sequence
constructor is non-empty then the select attribute must be absent. If
the select attribute is absent and the sequence constructor is empty,
then the result of the instruction is a text node whose string value
is zero-length. The way in which the value is constructed is specified
in 5.7.2 Constructing Simple Content.
[ERR XTSE0870] It is a static error if the select attribute of the
xsl:value-of element is present when the content of the element is
non-empty.
If the separator attribute is present, then the effective value of
this attribute is used to separate adjacent items in the result
sequence, as described in 5.7.2 Constructing Simple Content. In the
absence of this attribute, the default separator is a single space
(#x20) when the content is specified using the select attribute, or a
zero-length string when the content is specified using a sequence
constructor.

This has nothing to do with sorting, that is just the (enhanced) behaviour of xsl:value-of select since XSLT 2.
